# Unit test. Why Mock returns different value in second loop iteration?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have a Mock on the following object whose job is to collect sensor data. It implements this interface:

```
public interface ISensorDataCollector
{
    List<int> CollectSensorData(int amountOfValues);        
}
```

Inside the test I have the following arrangement:

```
// ARRANGE
var collector = new Mock<ISensorDataCollector>() { CallBase = true };
// Mock SensorDataCollector
collector.Setup((x) => x.CollectSensorData(10)
         .Returns(new List<int> { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9});
myProcess.AdwSensorDataCollector = collector.Object;

// ACT
myProcess.CollectSensorDataRepeatIfFails(5);
```

The Method to be tested has a while loop in which the data gets collected. The simple Version looks the following way:

```
public ISensorDataCollector SensorDataCollector { get; set; }

public void CollectSensorDataRepeatIfFails(int counterForRepeatedMeasurement)
{        
    do
    {
        List<int> values = this.SensorDataCollector.CollectSensorData(10); 

        values.Clear();

        counterForRepeatedMeasurement--;
    } while (counterForRepeatedMeasurement >= 0);
}
```

The problem: from the second iteration on the line `this.AdwSensorDataCollector.CollectSensorData(10);` returns an empty list. But I expected it to return the value that I specified in the setup each time:

```
collector.Setup((x) => x.CollectSensorData(10)
         .Returns(new List<int> { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9});
```

I guess it has something to do with `values.Clear();`, because if I remove the list-clearing. The return value of `CollectSensorDataRepeatIfFails` remains the same in all iterations, and my problem disappears. But that is only a guess. I really would like to know why the second call does not return specified return value.

Question: What did I miss? Does the setup works only for 1 invokation of the mocked method? or is there a button that I forgot to press to make it behave the expected way? Why does the clearing of the list affect the return value of the second call of the mocked method? Can someone please shed light on this matter?

I did a little research before asking, but I could only find posts which explain how to make the mock to return different values at next call. But no post where the problem arises using a loop. I would also be happy about a duplicate tip.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What did I miss? Does the setup work only for 1 invocation of the mocked method?

Actually this is expected behavior of the mock. The setup is mutable in the sense that you can change captured arguments or return value by reference. You are doing exactly that by `values.Clear();`. To avoid this issue just defer the creation of the list by providing factory. Something like this:

```
collector.Setup((x) => x.CollectSensorData(10))
    .Returns<int>((i) => new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 });
```

Comment: wonderfull, thank you. That makes a lot of sense. I modified your solution a little : `.Returns(() => { return new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }; });` I can only accept 1 answer, so I will accept this answer, because it has also a solution additional to the explanation. I upvoted both answers though

Answer (score 4):

This is expected behavior, because you are working with references of that list. No matter you return it from mock, or somewhere else.

```
collector.Setup((x) => x.CollectSensorData(10)
    .Returns(new List<int> { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9});
```

You are registering **reference** to `List<int>`.

`List<int> values = this.AdwSensorDataCollector.CollectSensorData(10);`

So in this call you are receiving reference to **exact same** `List<int>` object.

`values.Clear()`

Calling this is removing all items for the **same exact list** that mock should return.

You can read more about reference types here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types

**Update:**
You can use `.Callback(() => new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3})` instead of `Returns`. In this case callback will be called each time you call mocked function.

Comment: wonderfull, thank you. That makes a lot of sense. My expectation was that each call of `CollectSensorData` it would return a new list. But if the mock simply keeps the reference at reuses it again, that is of course the expected behaviour.

Comment: @MongZhu I updated question, so you can use it for your intended behavior.

Comment: I can only accept 1 answer, Johnny Bravo was faster, but I upvoted both answers though.